# How do I limit permissions using ShellExecute on remote desktop users

Tags: windows, winapi

Delphi XE app running on Windows 2012 Server.  How do I limit the user's permissions when they open Adobe Viewer using ShellExecute.  As it stands now, the uses are not permitted to see the drivers on the server.  However, when the user opens a pdf from the application, the permissions revert back to admin, which allows them to see and access the drives.

Are there settings within ShellExecute that can apply the proper permissions based on the user login credentials?

Comment: By "permissions" are you actually talking about a group policy setting?  How exactly are you preventing the users from seeing the drives on the server?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a process using `ShellExecute`, the new process runs under the credentials of the parent process. So it would seem that the process with is calling `ShellExecute` has more rights than you wish to grant to the process that is started by `ShellExecute`.

One way to solve the problem would be to call `ShellExecute` from a process running under the desired credentials. There may be other ways to solve it, but without any knowledge of your network security configuration, it's unlikely that we can give you much more specific advice.

Comment: We are limiting permissions with group policies.  I can check this by logging into the server as someone with limited permissions and trying to run the specific app called by ShellExecute.  In this case it is Adobe Reader.  When I start it from the server, the drives are not visible during a "Save as".  However, when I sign into my Delphi App as the same user, and call Adobe Reader from the app with the ShellExecute call, the drives are visible during a "Save as".